# Run time errors : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContext') angular

Tags: angular, typescript, adminlte

I'm getting this errors at run time : **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContext')  angular**:

We are using fllowing package and versions:

```
"@angular/animations": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^10.1.3",
"@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
"@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/localize": "^10.0.14",
"@angular/material": "^10.1.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^2.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^25.0.0",
"admin-lte": "^3.0.5",
"file-saver": "^2.0.2",
"firebase": "^7.22.1",
"firebase-tools": "^8.13.1",
"ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.2",
"ngx-guided-tour": "^1.1.11",
"rxjs": "~6.5.5",
"save": "^2.4.0",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"xlsx": "^0.16.7",
"zone.js": "~0.10.3"
```

Im using chrome browser, console error messages:

```
> zone-evergreen.js:171 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'getContext')
>     at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (dashboard2.js:15)
>     at e (jquery.min.js:2)
>     at t (jquery.min.js:2)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
>     at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
>     at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:480)
>     at ZoneTask.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:469)
>     at timer (zone-evergreen.js:2552)
```

Tried to clear all the content of dashboard2.js file:
from **node_modules\admin-lte\dist\js\pages\dashboard2.js**,Again getting another issue, browser console error messages:

```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'getContext')
>         at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scripts.js:2597)
>         at e (scripts.js:2)
>         at t (scripts.js:2)
>         at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:709)
>         at Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:481)
>         at invokeTask (polyfills.js:790)
>         at ZoneTask.invoke (polyfills.js:779)
>         at timer (polyfills.js:2845)
```

Comment: whats on '(dashboard2.js:15)' ?

Comment: It is one of the file of a AdminLTE library

Comment: File Path:  node_modules\admin-lte\dist\js\pages\dashboard2.js

Comment: do you have a custom js file that calls getContext ?